# Elasticsearch Point In Time Request API in Golang

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the point in time api in golang using the official [go-elasticsearch](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch) library. I can't seem to find any documentation that explains how to use it.

I've been able to create a `OpenPointInTime` object and retrieve a PIT id. I can't figure out what to do with it or where to place it in the `elasticsearch.Client.Search` function. I haven't been able to to find an example either.
Can anyone give a basic example using the official library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the closed issues on the github repo of the elasticsearch library, I found this issue thread: https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/issues/234

According to this thread, I need to get a PIT id from `OpenPointInTime` response and add it to the body.
This worked for me:

```
var query_buffer bytes.Buffer
body := `
    {
        "query": {
            "term": {
                "_id": "AkUN7YUB2JzVdyKtJ8bD"
            }
        },
        "pit": {
            "id":  "your pit id here", 
            "keep_alive": "3m"  
        }
    }
`
es, _ := elasticsearch.NewDefaultClient()
json.NewDecoder(&query_buffer).Decode(&body)
res, err := es.Search(
    es.Search.WithAllowPartialSearchResults(true),
    es.Search.WithBody(&query_buffer),
)
```